# Font becomes blurry in chromium browsers when scrolling after an AJAX call

Tags: html, css, ajax, chromium

When calling an Ajax function then manually scrolling to the top of the page some elements become blurry and thicker/darker. Especially noticeable on  tags. Added info: The ajax call in question did not target the affected text in any way, it simple changed the rendered partial in a div further down the page.

[Here is before the issue occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwc6F.png)

[And after an Ajax call while the title was not on screen, and then scrolling back up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAiEC.png)

I have verified that no changes to the CSS or markup are occurring, and also confirmed that the various fixes for a previously known issue with hardware acceleration mentioned [here](https://www.askvg.com/fix-blurry-text-and-font-display-problems-in-google-chrome/) do not resolve the issue.

Comment: Then the added div is the reason for it. Maybe the font-size is getting set to comma pixel values, these might cause rendering issues if content changes. Do you view the page zoomed in? Do you have scaling activated on your monitor? All of this can affect this

Comment: I have done side by side comparisons of the CSS and nothing changes, also resizing the screen, opening dev tools, or if devtools is already open selecting the element picker causes it to immediately go back to normal. Im taking this as indication its a renderer issue as anything that causes a refresh of the render (not the page) fixes the weird rendering.

Comment: This still sounds totally like some comma values für something. Either font size, margin, height.. whatever. Once you change the size of the page values get recalculated and it fixes itself. Not much we can help here except to tell you to check all your styles, maybe you can identify something.

Comment: I shall be sure to check these after the holidays then. Thank you for your help. Merry Christmas.